# Running GWT application on apache tomcat 8

Tags: gwt, java-8, remote-debugging, tomcat8

I'm developing a GWT(2.6.0) application with eclipse kepler, java 7 & external tomcat server 7. Recently the external web server is upgraded to latest tomcat 8.
I'm sure that I've changed all configurations correctly in eclipse debugging environment, but when I want to start server in debug mode I get a JSP compilation error & I can't start debugging.
Is GWT 2.6 compatible with tomcat server 8.0? and what about java 8 support by GWT?

Comment: Please post the error message. Java 8 isn't supported yet by current the official release (2.6.1), but it's planned for 3.0 (or maybe even 2.7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.- Yes GWT works perfectly with TC 8.0

2.- Java 8 support will be available in GWT-3.0.0, probably in 2015 Q1. Actually there are patches coming to GWT master trunk related with this. https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/9260/